# swap css class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link that, when clicked expands into a div below. I need to add some sort of indicator to "My Link", like a "carrot" icon that will turn down to indicate expanding of the section. Basically I thought I need to add the icon in a css class and then swap that class with another that has different image. I found toggleClass bit it seems like it adds/removes the class instead of swapping it.

So how would I replace class?

Here's what I have now without adding the visual indicator.

```
$("#mLink").click(function() {
    $("#showHideDiv").slideToggle("fast");
});

<span id="mLink">My Link</span>
<div id="showHideDiv">
   hidden content
</div>
```

I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should invoke [`.toggle()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Like

```
$('#myLink').toggle(function() {
    $("#showHideDiv").slideDown("fast").toggleClass('open');
}, function() {
    $("#showHideDiv").slideUp("fast").toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just string 2 toggles together something like

`$('#myDiv').toggleClass('a').toggleClass('b');`

and have your target start with one of the classes..

`<div id="myDiv" class="b"> bla bla </div>`

and then each call will toggle both giving the result you want.

Comment: +1 IMO this is the best way - simple and uncomplicated. Works perfectly